# How to show text on hover only in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone I get some code from a website I was trying to modify it but unable to do it here is code what I want to hide `<h2>` tag content only visible when I hover on it I tried display: none; and in hover display:block; also visibilty: hidden or visible but I didn't work for me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="hovereffect">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
<div class="overlay">
<h2>Effect 12</h2>
<p> 
<a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
</p> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #42b078;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: transparent;

}

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add `visibility: hidden;` to this block:

```
.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  /* here */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And i add this block for showing the overlay after hovering on `.hovereffect`:

```
.hovereffect:hover .overlay{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Final css:

```
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #42b078;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay{
  visibility: visible;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: transparent;

}

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jbg6tmLh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1566fy1/)

```
.overlay h2{
  opacity:0
}
.overlay h2:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:none;` to your `.hovereffect h2` code, then add the following css:

```
.hovereffect:hover h2{
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/87cf2Lhy/

Answer (score 0):

For things such as transitions and animations, **you want to avoid changing the DOM flow as much as possible**.

Even though you are using these things on an overlay and won't make that much of a serious performance hit, you should avoid using `display: none` and then changing its value to block. This way you will get used to better CSS practices.

**The best approach here is to use opacity.**

The logic is simple:

```
element {
  opacity: 0;
}

element:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #42b078;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}
.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2>Effect 12</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```